# Returning a number

Tags: c++

I'm still very new to C++, and seem to have an issue. When I run my program, my `getInt()` doesn't seem to be returning the private data member, `myInteger`, in my `print()` method. It just returns 0, but the rest of my method calls in `print()` are returning the appropriate number. I've also tried to just type in `myInteger` instead of `getInt()`, but that still comes back with 0. I know I did something wrong, but I'm not really sure what.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

class myInt {
public:
  myInt();
  myInt(int newInt);

  void print();
  void setInt(int);

  int getInt();
  int sumDigits();
  int reverse();

  int oddDigitCount();
  int evenDigitCount();
  int zeroCount();

private:
  int myInteger;
};

int main()
{
    srand(815);

    myInt theNum;
    for (int i = 0; i != 10; i++) {
        theNum.setInt(rand());
        theNum.print();
    }

  return 0;
}

myInt::myInt()
{
    myInteger = 0;
}

myInt::myInt(int newInt)
{
    setInt(newInt);
}

void myInt::setInt(int newInt)
{
    if (newInt > 0)
        myInteger = newInt;
    else
        myInteger = abs(newInt);
}

int myInt::getInt()
{
    return myInteger;
}

int myInt::sumDigits()
{
    int sum = 0, rem;
    while (myInteger != 0) {
        rem = myInteger % 10;
        sum += rem;
        myInteger /= 10;
    }
   return sum;
}

int myInt::reverse()
{
    int reversed = 0;
    int quo, rem;
    quo = myInteger;
    while (quo != 0) 
    {
        rem = quo % 10;
        reversed = reversed * 10 + rem;
        quo /= 10;
    }
   return reversed;
}

int myInt::oddDigitCount()
{
    return 0;
}

int myInt::evenDigitCount()
{
    return 0;
}

int myInt::zeroCount()
{
    return 0;
}

void myInt::print()
{
    cout << "The number is " << getInt() << endl
         << "----------------------------------------" << endl
         << "Adding the digits result" << setw(16) << sumDigits() << endl
         << "Reversing the digits result" << setw(13) << reverse() << endl  
         << "Odd digits" << setw(30) << oddDigitCount() << endl
         << "Even digits" << setw(29) << evenDigitCount() << endl
         << "Zeros" << setw(35) << zeroCount() << endl
         << endl;
}
```

Output for first two iterations of for loop,

> The number is 0
>
> ---
>
> Adding the digits result               9
>
> Reversing the digits result           72
>
> Odd digits                             0
>
> Even digits                            0
>
> Zeros                                  0
>
> The number is 0
>
> ---
>
> Adding the digits result              20
>
> Reversing the digits result        41681
>
> Odd digits                             0
>
> Even digits                            0
>
> Zeros                                  0

Comment: Please post real code that actually compiles, instead of fantasy code. `myInt(int) {setInt(newInt);}` this is not going to compile.

Comment: Forgot to make it `myInt( int newInt) {setInt(newInt);}` when I posted it here. My bad, my actual code did not have that issue.

Comment: Seems to [work for me](http://rextester.com/LLVX33387)

Comment: That's interesting.. I'm using Dev C++ to compile. Maybe it's just that then?

Comment: remove the whole `print` otherwise define what you call inside it

Comment: I'm sorry, I left out methods that I thought weren't needed in order to save space.

Comment: where is your problem then?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: In my `print()`, `getInt()` isn't returning the data member, in my output it just displays 0. But as stated above it seems to work outside the compiler I'm using (Dev C++).

Comment: who said that it is not returning data member?? your data is random `srand()`

Comment: no. it works perfect

Comment: add semicolon to: `cout << "The number is " << getInt() << endl;`

Comment: Again, in the compiler I was using, Dev C++, it's not displaying properly. I've went ahead and added in the other methods. `sumDigits()` and `reverse()` are doing their jobs, but when it comes to displaying the single number, it displays 0.

Comment: Dev-C++ isn't even a compiler. And you're not showing us the real code and real output.

Comment: Went through and updated the whole code, and added output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int myInt::sumDigits()
{
    int sum = 0, rem;
    while (myInteger != 0) {
        rem = myInteger % 10;
        sum += rem;
        myInteger /= 10;  // <-- HERE
    }
   return sum;
}
```

This code resets `myInteger` back to 0 before you print it.

You call it as part of this statement:

```
cout << "The number is " << getInt() << endl
     << "----------------------------------------" << endl
     << "Adding the digits result" << setw(16) << sumDigits() << endl
     << ...
```

The compiler apparently has chosen to evaluate the call to `sumDigits` before the call to `getInt` (C++ leaves this order unspecified), so by the time `getInt` looks at `myInteger`, it's already been set to 0 by `sumDigits`.

To fix this, do the same thing you do in `reverse`: Create a local variable (such as `quo`), which you can modify without affecting anything else.

Comment: Thanks! Fixed it, and also learned about the importance of adding more of my code than what I think is needed.

Comment: :o I coudn't had realized that but, it makes sense, because both calls are in the same sentence, so, there's no sequence points between evaluations. Anyway,  instead of creating a new variable to copy the object, make it a separate sentence: `cout << "The number is " << getInt() << endl;` and later the rest of the output. That way, you ensure `getInt()` is evaluated first.

Comment: @Peregring-lk It's much better to make sure `sumDigits` has no side effects because then it doesn't matter when it's evaluated. You can make the compiler enforce parts of this by marking the methods const: `int sumDigits() const;` etc.

Comment: Ok, I thought you was talking about creating a copy of the integer inside the print function. And yes of course, it has no sense that `sumDigits` has side effects. Anyway, if it were any other function with "expected" side effects, the simplest thing is making them separate statements.